Redirect Não Está Funcionando
O redirecionamento do método return não está acontecendo nem mesmo retornar a pagina html está funcionando oque posso fazer para resolver isso?
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class C_Usuario {

@Autowired
private S_Usuario sUsuario;

@GetMapping("/login")
public String getLogin() {
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping("/validar")
public String postLogin(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                          @RequestParam("senha") String senha,
                          RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    if (sUsuario.isUsuario(email, senha)){
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem",
                "Usuario Existe seu Login vai Funcionar");
        return "redirect:/usuario/login";
    }

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem",
            "Usuario não Existe seu Login não vai Funcionar");

    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/cadastro")
public String getCadastro() {
    return "cadastro/cadastro";
}

@PostMapping("/cadastrar")
public String postCadastro(@RequestParam("nome") String nome,
                          @RequestParam("email") String email,
                          @RequestParam("senha") String senha) {
    if (sUsuario.cadastrar(nome, email, senha)) {
        return "redirect:/usuario/login";
    }

    return "cadastro/cadastro";
}
}


Boas-vindas. Não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações fornecidas nos comentários da pergunta original. Se precisar comentar faça-o na pergunta original também.
